# Java String Matching in a Sorted File and grouping similar data

Tags: java, regex, file, string-matching

i have sorted file and i need to do the following pattern match. I read the row and then compare or do patern match with the row just after it , if it matches then insert the string i used to match after a comma in that row and move on to the next row. I am new to Java and overwhelmed with options from Open CSV to BufferedReader. I intend to iterate through the file till it reaches the end. I may always have blanks and have a dated in quotes. The file size would be around 100 MBs.
My file has data like

```
ABCD
ABCD123
ABCD456, 123 
XYZ
XYZ890
XYZ123, 890
```

and output is expected as

```
ABCD, ABCD
ABCD123, ABCD
ABCD456, 123, ABCD
XYZ, XYZ
XYZ890, XYZ
XYZ123, 890, XYZ
```

Not sure about the best method. Can you please help me.

Comment: the simplest is usually the best

Comment: what is expected output of above sample?

Comment: @user3218114 just updated the expected result. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To open a file, you can use File and FileReader classes:

```
File csvFile = new File("file.csv");

FileReader fileReader = null;
try {
    fileReader = new FileReader(csvFile);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can get a line of the file using Scanner:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(fileReader);

while(reader.hasNext()){
    String line = reader.nextLine();
    parseLine(line);
}
```

You want to parse this line. For it, you have to study [Regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) for using Pattern and Matcher classes:

```
private void parseLine(String line) {
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(ABCD)").matcher(line);
    if(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println("find: " + matcher.group());
    }
}
```

To find the next pattern of the same row, you can reuse matcher.find(). If some result was found, it will return true and you can get this result with matcher.groud();

Comment: Thanks, I guess i can parse the line with string split too , but how do I traverse down the next line till my pattern breaks and insert data of the grouped string. Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Read line by line and use regex to replace it as per your need using `String.replaceAll()`

```
^([A-Z]+)([0-9]*)(, [0-9]+)?$
```

Replacement : `$1$2$3, $1`

Here is [Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/uE4eD1/2)

Read more about [Java Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

---

Sample code:

```
String regex = "^([A-Z]+)([0-9]*)(, [0-9]+)?$";
String replacement = "$1$2$3, $1";

String newLine = line.replaceAll(regex,replacement);
```

---

For better **performance**, read 100 or more lines at a time and store in a buffer and finally call `String#replaceAll()` single time to replace all at a time.

sample code:

```
String regex = "([A-Z]+)([0-9]*)(, [0-9]+)?(\r?\n|$)";
String replacement = "$1$2$3, $1$4";

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
int counter = 0;
String line = null;
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("abc.csv"))) {
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        builder.append(line).append(System.lineSeparator());
        if (counter++ % 100 == 0) { // 100 lines
            String newLine = builder.toString().replaceAll(regex, replacement);
            System.out.print(newLine);
            builder.setLength(0); // reset the buffer
        }
    }
}
if (builder.length() > 0) {
    String newLine = builder.toString().replaceAll(regex, replacement);
    System.out.print(newLine);
}
```

Read more about [Java 7 - The try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)